# Pyspark change list to RDD type wihtout changing id

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Assume I have this in pyspark:

```
# 1 million elements in data list
data = [ { "a": 1, "b" : 1 }, { "a" : 2, "b" : 2 }, { "a" : 3, "b" : 3 }..... ]
```

I want a part of data list to do map reduce by using RDD :

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(  master = 'spark://192.168.56.103:7077',appName = 'test' )
rdd = sc.parallelize( A_Part_Of_Data_List )
rdd.map( lambda x : DO_SOMETHING() if x['a']>100 else x )
```

But when I use `sc.parallelize()` to change `A_Part_Of_Data_List` to RDD type, the memory address (id) of `A_Part_Of_Data_List` elements have also been changed.

The change in RDD will not change in original data.

Is it possible to change list type to RDD type without changing id of elemants ?

Comment: In which context are you creating this data list?

Comment: @KenrySanchez What do you mean?

Comment: Why are you using rdd. Have you tried using spark dataframe.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, what is the expected result. When you're calling `parallelize`, your data is being distributed among multiple worker nodes, and being processed there. Later you can collect it back and see processing results. Any modifications to RDD would not change original data in executor's memory.